# SQL Server - Select top 10 providers based on charge amounts from 3rd quarter

Tags: sql-server

I'm having some trouble figuring out what I need to do to make this work and meet these requirements:

> Generate a SELECT statement that figures out the top 10 providers from
>   the credit db based on total charge amounts from the 3rd quarter.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select top 10 provider_no, charge_amt, charge_dt
from charge
group by provider_no 
order by charge_amt desc;
```

Could I get some help finishing this query so it shows only 10 lines and doesn't have repeating provider_no's sorted by the charge_amt with the charge_dt in the 3rd quarter of the year?

Comment: What is the table(s) structure? columns names?

Comment: provider_no is a column of ints identifying providers, charge_amt is a column of the data type money with various amounts that were charged, and charge_dt is a column with the dates of the charges. Is there any other info you need?

Comment: Does your table contain data for a single year only?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is only one year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that charge_dt is a date time of the charge. So the statement should look like:

```
select top 10 provider_no, datepart(qq, charge_dt), sum(charge_amt)
from charge
where datepart(qq, charge_dt) = 3
group by provider_no, datepart(qq, charge_dt)
order by sum(charge_amt) desc
```

Comment: This is looking good. Is there any way to still show the date (charge_dt) within the 3rd quarter instead of just showing 3?

Comment: it has no sense to me - becase statement is grouping charges by dates in the quarter. anyway you can replace `datepart(qq, charge_dt) `(both in select an group by clause) to something like `cast(datepart(yyyy, charge_dt) as nvarchar) + '/' + cast(datepart(qq, charge_dt) as nvarchar)`

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. Thanks for your help!